# Beginner Looking for Guidance on Methods

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to complete a project where we have to take a set of data of random numbers between 0 and 364 and see what percentage of the runs (the method takes the number of items in the data set and the number of runs) have a duplicate number in them.

Below is what I have so far, but I am really struggling to figure out how to do this as I keep getting errors:

```
public double calculate(int size, int count) {

    double percentage;
    int matches = 0;
    int check;
    int i = 0;
    int add = 0;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    List<Integer> birthdays = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int k = 1; k <= count; k++){
        rnd.setSeed(k);
        do{
            add = rnd.nextInt(365);
            birthdays.add(add);
            i++;
        }while (i < size-1);
        //birthdays.add(rnd.nextInt());
        for (int j = 0; j <= size-1; j++) {
            check = birthdays.get(j);
            if (birthdays.indexOf(check) != birthdays.lastIndexOf(check)) {
                matches++;
                j = size;
            }
        }
       }

    percentage = (double)matches / count * 100;

   //percentage = 8;

   return percentage;
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: OutofBoundsException

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong with regard to even answering the question. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What's the difference between the size and count params

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code here. One is the while loop directly after the first for loop that doesn't seem to be doing anything. It says:

```
while(i < size-1);
```

That might be giving you an error, but error you are talking about is probably from your second for loop. When you instantiate it you say:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= size-1; j++)
```

but then you say:

```
j = size;
```

since when you instantiate it you say j<=size-1 but then you set j=size it will give an error.